# How to fetch data to ComboBox from a Linq query?

Tags: c#, database, winforms, linq, combobox

I wanted get set of data and append to combobox from database using linq.

I have did it already but when i save data. My db saved value looks like this:

```
{ 
  schid = 1004, 
  schoolname = St John Bossco 
}
```

I only wanted to save the string value of the school name. how can i approach that?

This is my code:

```
private void get_combo_vale_list()
{
  using (DBEntity db = new DBEntity())
  {
    var school = db.basicdata_school.Select(x => new { x.schid, x.schoolname });
    cmbalschool.DataSource = school.ToList();
    cmbalschool.ValueMember = "schid";
    cmbalschool.DisplayMember = "schoolname";
    cmbalschool.SelectedItem = null
    }
}
```

Comment: your code is correct .just change selectedItem .That should not null.                                         cmbalschool.SelectedItem = cmbalschool.Items[0];

Comment: The question is not clear to me? Do you want to get `schoolname` of item which selected in combobox?